# How to fix soft bricked Samsung Galaxy Tab A 10.1 after /data reformat

Tags: samsung

I jot got brand new Galaxy Tab A 10.1 tablet (580 model running Android 6). After using Odin 3.12.1 to install TWRP 3.0.2-0 custom recovery I tried to do a full image backup and it failed with "can't mount /data (Invalid argument). So I Googled around and found the "[SOLVED] Cant mount /data" video https://youtu.be/X7yDPszoQ5s that suggested to change data partition type from ext4 to exFat. After that the tablet does not boot and gives some criptic error about data encryption and dropping devices. Nothing, even factory reset helps. I read that Samsung does some encryption but I am not Android expert. Can someone help?

Comment: Tried flashing a [factory firmware](https://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/database/SM-T580/) via Odin?

Comment: I tried that already following this http://www.factory-settings.com/firmware-update/stock-rom-samsung-galaxy-tab-a-10-1-sm-t580-2016.html

Answer (score -1):

The solution was to choose "Format data" in TWRP.